# Create a shortcut to easily open corresponding hpp or cpp files in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Say I am in a.cpp. What's the easiest way to set up a shortcut that would open (or would focus) a.hpp?

Something similar to the vim script found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to this is by using the builtin shorcut: Alt + o.

See Goto > Switch File > Switch Header/Implementation

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is already exists for this command in sublime text

> Preferences > Key Bindings

Here you can see something like that

> "command": "switch_file"

Shortcuts are:

- Linux: alt+o
- Mac OS: super+alt+up

In menu:

> Goto > Switch File > Switch Header/Implementation