# Sublime Text 3: How go to header file from #include directive?

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext3

I have been using Sublime Text 3 for quite some time recently for C/C++ development.

I am pretty happy with everything except I need to go to a header file from an #include directive.

I have been searching pretty much everywhere ... no luck so far.

Please let me know your comments.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking but I googled "sublime text 3 open header file site:stackoverflow.com" and came up with several previous questions (google is rather more effective at searching than SO's feeble offering).

Comment: @WeatherVane I specifically mentioned in the title that I need to be able to go to a header file included via #include directive but not the hpp file corresponding to a c++ file as there are many solution for the later; however there is none for the former.

Comment: No, you did not specifically mention [opening .hpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663409/create-a-shortcut-to-easily-open-corresponding-hpp-or-cpp-files-in-sublime-text) is ok but .h is a problem. You only mentioned "C/C++" whatever that is. So you don't really want the `c++` tag?

Comment: @WeatherVane Believe me this would sound crystal clear to a C/C++ Sublime Text 3 user. Leave that to an expert. It would get sorted out sooner or later. Many thanks;